# Expect - does not send text as desired

Tags: linux, send, expect

I am developing a script to be used for regression testing of installation of a software.  The expect code is given below.  The first few lines of code run well where the license file is browsed and agreed to.  However, the script halts at "Please enter the pathname to a valid license file:" and does not do anything.  (Note: Manually the installation proceeds smoothly).

Also, please note that the cursur for all the inputs is always located to the right of the displayed text; but in the case of the last prompt ("Please enter the pathname to a valid license file:") the cursor is located below the text and in the line below.  I am not sure if this has to do anything with the issue.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I debug this issue?  I appreciate any help from you all.

Thanks
Nazir

**Here is the code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./temp 
expect {
         "More--*" {
               send " "
                exp_continue
                }
"Do you accept this license agreement?*" {
                 send "yes\r"
                 }
}
expect "Do you want to use the default path?*" { send "yes\r" }
expect "This load path does not exist. Do you want to create it?*" { send "yes\r" }
expect "Please enter the pathname to a valid license file:*" { send "/path_to_file\r" }
interact
```

**Here is how the output looks:**

```
.....(license stuff)

Do you accept this license agreement? [no] yes

Please specify where the xxx software will be loaded.
The default location is /usr/local/aaa.
Do you want to use the default path? [yes] yes

The software will not run without a valid license file installed.
Please enter the pathname to a valid license file:
```

Comment: You're missing `\r` at the end of `send "/path_to_file"`. Is that in the real script or a copy error here?

Comment: Hi Barnar...Thanks pointing out ...it is a copy error and I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can debug in expect with the -d switch:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -d
```

It's pretty verbose and has helped me nail down countless little typos I've made while writing in expect.

Comment: Thanks, I did something similar...I used autoexpect and compared the code generated!